# How I can access to DOM node inside of withStyle component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-with-styles

I'm working on `react` project and in this project my colleagues and I are using `Material UI`, for some reason I wanna access to `DOM node` of another component that wrapped by a `HOC`. I used  react `ref` for this. but I just get the `withStyle` object, see below:

This is my `TableHead`:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { TableHead as MaterialTableHead, TableRow } from '@material-ui/core';
import TableCell from './TableCell';

const TableHead = ({ classes, head, ...rest }) => (
  <MaterialTableHead {...rest}>
    <TableRow>
      {head.map(item => (
        <TableCell key={item.key} className={classes.headCell} style={{ width: item.width }}>
          {item.title}
        </TableCell>
      ))}
    </TableRow>
  </MaterialTableHead>
);

TableHead.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  head: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    key: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    width: PropTypes.string,
    render: PropTypes.func,
  })).isRequired,
};

TableHead.defaultProps = {};

const styles = () => ({
  headCell: {
    fontSize: '18px',
    color: '#0c1d38',
  },
});

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(TableHead);
```

And in the `Table` component I wanna calculate height of `TableHead` component, so I use below code:

```
<TableHead ref={(header) => { this.header = header; }} head={head} />
```

and inside of `componentDidMount` of `Table` component I `console.log(this.header)` and just see below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVhAW.png)

I seek in the web and find some `GitHub` issues pages and try `innerRef` instead of `ref` but it doesn't help me.

How I can access to DOM node to calculate its height?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `innerRef` property. Just replace `ref` with `innerRef`.

Example:

```
<TableHead innerRef={(header) => { this.header = header; }} head={head} />
```

## Source (`withStyles` docs):

> Some implementation details that might be interesting to being aware
>   of:
>
> It adds a classes property so you can override the injected class
>   names from the outside.
>
> **It adds an innerRef property so you can get a reference to the wrapped component. The usage of innerRef is identical to ref.**
>
> It forwards non React static properties so this HOC is more
>   "transparent". For instance, it can be used to defined a
>   getInitialProps() static method (next.js).

Reference: https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles---options----higher-order-component

Comment: The result of `innerRef` is: `Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail`. because the `TableHeader` is a stateless function, how I can solve it ?

Comment: Do you have an Idea for me?

Comment: Same problem here, couldn't find anything on github except https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/10106

Answer (score 0):

I know it’s late, but for other people which might face this problem I provide my solution, too. Material UI has a **[RootRef API](https://material-ui.com/api/root-ref/#rootref-api)** which you can use a as HOC the case you want to get the element DOM node:

First import the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import RootRef from '@material-ui/core/RootRef';
```

Then wrap your entire element inside a RootRef component and create a React ref. But instead of adding a ref on your component and reference it to the ref like this `ref={this.tableHeadRef}`, you should add `rootRef` to the rootRef HOC and reference it to your ref like this: `rootRef={this.tableHeadRef}` to get the current DOM node. This can be applied to any component that uses withStyles HOC.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.tableHeadRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.tableHeadRef.current); // DOM node
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <RootRef rootRef={this.tableHeadRef}>
        <TableHead />
      </RootRef>
    );
  }
}
```